# Firebase ListView

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
n = ref.child(key).child("customer");

n.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        getData(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        getData(dataSnapshot);
    }

    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});
```

And the `getData` function looks like this.

```
private void getData(DataSnapshot ds){
  arrayList.clear();
  for(DataSnapshot data:ds.getChildren()){
    People p = new People();
    p.setName(data.getValue(People.class).getName());
    arrayList.add(p.getName());
  }

  if(arrayList.size()>0){
    ArrayAdapter a = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listview.setAdapter(a);
  }
}
```

It's showing

> Unfortunate error and closing the program (App crashes)

Where did I go wrong? Under the customer key there are a number of unique keys generated by push, I want to get the inside data (names) in the `ListView`.

Here's my logcat

```
PID: 2906 com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:‌​185 at com.example.ahmedimam.firebase2.MainActivity.getData(MainAct‌​ivity.java:151)
```

MainActivity 151 points out to

```
p.setName(data.getValue(People.class).getName());
```

If I change it to `p.setName(data.getValue().toString);` - its working but it shows the last added key with full children and I want to get the name only of every auto generated key..

Comment: The community recently discussed [the addition of urgent begging to questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) and decided that it prefers posts without such requests.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: PID: 2906                                                                           com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185   at com.example.ahmedimam.firebase2.MainActivity.getData(MainActivity.java:151)

Comment: MainActivity 151 points out to  p.setName(data.getValue(People.class).getName()); if i change it to p.setName(data.getValue().toString); its working but it shows the last added key with full children and i want to get the name only of every auto generated key..

Answer (score 0):

This is  a correct & tested code for Displaying firebase children in a listview...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<String> mArraylistSectionLessons = new ArrayList<>();
public static String clickedItem;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");

    // List Views
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterLessons = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view,
            R.id.label, mArraylistSectionLessons);
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapterLessons);

    // Getting All Keys From Firebase Query
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String value = child.getKey();
                mArraylistSectionLessons.add(value);
                arrayAdapterLessons.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }

    });
    // listening to single list item on click
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            clickedItem =(String) (mListView.getItemAtPosition(position));
            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);


            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra(clickedItem, clickedItem);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Resources : "Master Android" Application

Comment: This answer may answer the question, but this is more like a generic answer for retrieving data from Firebase database. Please be more specific.

Comment: This is the best Answer i really found... But for more info , you can see the "Master Android" Application that i found this code in it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData` function should look like this.

```
private void getData(DataSnapshot ds){
  arrayList.clear();
  for(DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()){
    People p = new People();
    p = data.getValue(People.class);

    arrayList.add(p.getName());
  }

  if(arrayList.size() > 0){
    ArrayAdapter a = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listview.setAdapter(a);
  }
}
```

Make the attributes of your `People` class `public`.